# Multiple keyword search in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, search, keyword-search

Here is my post method input from form. The Form includes search technique.
`What are the difference between AC motor and DC motor?`

I want the output to be
`What|difference|AC|motor|DC|motor`

But I am getting the output 
`What|||difference||AC|motor||DC|motor`

What am I doing wrong?

---

Here is my coding approach

```
<?php
include 'dbh.inc.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['search'])){

    $value = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['search']));
    $noSpace = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $value);
    $noCommon = removeCommonWords($noSpace);

    $replace = str_replace(' ', '|', $noCommon);

    echo $replace;

}



function removeCommonWords($input){

    // EEEEEEK Stop words
    $commonWords = array('a','able','about','above','abroad',..........);

    return preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|',$commonWords).')\b/','',$input);
}


?>
```

Comment: I have tried with this. But it does not replace the words that i don't want. But word are included in the array.
`return preg_replace('/\b('.implode(' ',$commonWords).')\b/','',$input);`

Here is the output
`What|are|the|difference|between|AC|motor|and|DC|motor`

Comment: try this `preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|',$commonWords).')(\s+)\b/','',$input);`

Comment: @Rainmx93 it's working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may match and *skip* common words and only match and keep other word chunks:

```
\b(?:are|the|between|and)\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\w+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ffiVGg/1).

**Details**

- `\b(?:are|the|between|and)\b` - whole words `are`, etc.
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - the PCRE verbs that discard the match and proceed looking for a next one from the end of the unsuccessful match
- `|` - or
- `\w+` - just match and keep 1 or more word chars.

Here is a [PHP snippet](https://3v4l.org/5uQ37):

```
$commonWords = ['are','the','between','and'];
$value = 'What are the difference between AC motor and DC motor?';
$rx = '~\b(?:' . implode('|', $commonWords) . ')\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\w+~u';
if (preg_match_all($rx, $value, $matches)) {
    echo implode('|', $matches[0]); // => What|difference|AC|motor|DC|motor
}
```